# Strapi v4 data (entries) lost overnight in local development - Postgres Database

Tags: sql, angular, database, postgresql, strapi

System Information

- Strapi Version: 4.4.3: Operating
- System: Windows 11
- Database: Postgres
- Node Version: 16.17.1
- NPM Version: 8.15.0
- Yarn Version: 1.22.19

Our team connected the Strapi app to a postgres database and we have created multiple collections and then we populated them with data(entries) in local development (yarn develop). Everything was working fine yesterday, as we did multiple re-builds and restarts. Today when I rebuilt and started the project with yarn develop, all of our collections where there, but the entries have been lost and we are looking for some answers, because we can’t find the logic behind this problem. Is this a problem with our database setup or it’s a strapi bug?
We are ready to provide more information and code as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and it seems that the issue here is that Strapi drops tables and recreates them. We noticed this behavior when we used a single development database in the team, and some of us created more entities and populated data and then, other team members started older Strapi commits without these entities in the code, and it got dropped.

Comment: You and your team have to keep your files in sync every time you individually start or refresh the project page while running. It’s because strapi keeps all collections in files and all entries in the database. Once a member of your team starts the project without the collections you created, all entries related to those collections get deleted. If you are a small team you can push your changes to a branch and inform your colleagues to pull before starting the project or modify your script to pull before starting the project. If you are a big team you must find a way to keep the files in sync.